# jquery document height memory usage

Tags: jquery, height

I am creating a modal window using jquery. I am having an issue with the page height when creating a overlay.

To set the overlay height I am using `$(document).height()` and this is working fine.
But if the page height increases as per the records the memory usage is doubled.

For Example if my page has 10 records and when I click on a link to open modal window the memory usage is changed from 68,000k to 75,000k.

If my page has 100 records, when I open modal window memory usage is 135,000k.

This is explicitly because of document height.

This is found in IE8.

Please help me out on how to get the document height without effecting the memory.

Comment: Can you put together a minimal test case replicating the problem and post it to your question. (And possibly *additionally* to http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net, but not *just* there.)

Comment: How can you check the amount of memory this object uses?

Comment: @ppumkin: If you are using windows OS, please refer to task manager -> processes section and sort with 'Mem usage'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating an overlay that covers the entire page, why not position the overlay using a fixed position relative to the viewport?

You could try the following CSS to achieve this:

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

This would avoid the requirement of continually increasing the height of the overlay and would cover the entirety of the viewport.

Comment: I tried with position: absolute and failed... 'fixed' is working perfect...Thanks michaelward82.

Answer (score 2):

IE8 supports css position:fixed which you can use to position the overlay and dialog without having to refer to the document height. Then you can just use something like

```
$("#myDialog").css({
    position: "fixed",
    top: ($(window).height() - $("#myDialog").outerHeight())/2
})
```

and css for the overlay

```
.overlay {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.ie7 .overlay, .ie8 .overlay {
    background: url("../img/lb-overlay.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; /*image is a 1px by 1px semi transparent png*/
}
```

This may or may not fix the memory problems, but is in general a better way to position a modal dialog (it only fails in ie6).